# Opencv GStreamer pipeline doesn't work on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: c++, opencv, gstreamer, raspberry-pi4, debian-buster

I'm trying to open UDP stream video in Raspberry Pi using this pipeline:

```
VideoCapture video("udpsrc port=5600 ! application/x-rtp,payload=96,encoding-name=H264 !"
                           "rtpjitterbuffer mode=1 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! appsink emit-signals=true sync=false max-buffers=2 drop=true", cv::CAP_GSTREAMER);
   // Exit if video is not opened
          if(!video.isOpened())
          {
              cout << "Could not read video file" << endl;
              return 1;
          }
```

However, `video.isOpened()` return false and I couldn't be able to open with this code. This works on loopback test and another Ubuntu 18.04 PC but RPi 4 (Buster OS) couldn't run it. Also following lines can run upcoming gstream video:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5600 caps='application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264' ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink fps-update-interval=1000 sync=false
```

Furthermore specific code stack (e.g. [video_udp.cpp][1]) can easily handle video but also it's hard to use with opencv.

NOTE: OpenCV version is 4.2.0-pre

Comment: This link suggests "apt-get update" "apt-get dist-upgrade -y" https://discuss.ardupilot.org/t/apsync-r-pi3-setup-issue/23090

Comment: On that topic the problem doesn't be solved. BTW, I tried update, upgrade etc. before and also seen some mentions about adding '/etc/apt/sources.list' http://vontaene.de to solve missing dependencies.

Comment: I found that the version of gstreamer is 1.14.4.1+b1 on raspberry pi while it is 1.14.5 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: The problem is that Raspberry pi 4 doesn't recognize Gstreamer library. Now, I'm trying with '-D WITH_GSTREAMER=ON' flag. If it's ok, I'll try to install all steps by checking carefully.

Comment: After you solved ur problem, please answer ur question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is about using GStreamer library as a plugin of OpenCV. OpenCV doesn't throw exception even you build source code without GStreamer support. (In default, GStreamer library was directly found by Ubuntu, conversely Raspberry Pi 4 couldn't find it.)

Firstly I check build information of OpenCV with `std::cout<<cv::getBuildInformation();` in Ubuntu 18.04 machine and found that:

**`GStreamer: YES (1.14.5)`**

Also I just check this on Raspberry Pi 4 side and build information was:

**`GStreamer:NO`**

Before the build OpenCV I just compare GStreamer plugins with `gst-inspect-1.0` command for both of them and I just install some missing plugins like `gstreamer1.0-tools` . Also I wasn't know the problem, before the checking build information, so I installed some other GStreamer plugins that currently I don't remember.

**Lastly,** I build system by adding `-D WITH_GSTREAMER=ON` flag. And now it works well.

I'll edit answer if the problem related to missing plugins those are installed later. For this, I'll check this issue with clean Buster OS image.